# How to produce bold MyriadPro font using sIFR?

Tags: sifr

I want to produce bold MyriadPro font. I have clicked **B** (Toggle the bold style) button and make the text in the white frame become bold. But Flash 8 always outputs a regular style font file.

Answer (score 1):

When you replace the HTML elements with sIFR, you'll still have to specify the bold font weight:

```
sIFR.replace(font, {
  css: '.sIFR-root { font-weight: bold; }
});
```

However, if you mean to say that the generated Flash movie does not contain the Myriad Pro Bold version, try selecting that specific font instead. Flash will usually apply a fake bold I think.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know how to do. It turns out that I forgot to install bold style font first.